Scientific calculator using js
I am buildinng a scientific calculator using js. The normal calculator part is working but my scientific calculator is not working. Earlier I was using `eval(  function for calculation but due to security issues, I have used tokenization method to build it.
The issue is the while using the trignometric calculation it is not working.
Here is the screenshot of it



const userInput = document.getElementById('input');
const userOutput = document.getElementById('output');
const clearbtn = document.getElementById('clear');
const calBtn = document.getElementById('calcBtn');
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');

function calc() {
  btns.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const btnDataType = button.dataset.type;

      if (btnDataType === 'number' || btnDataType === 'operator') {
        userInput.value += button.value;
      } else if (btnDataType === 'Soperator') {
        userInput.value += `${button.value}(`;
      }

      calBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let tokens = userInput.value.match(/(\d+(\.\d+)?)|[+\-*/%()]|sin|cos|tan/g);
        if (!tokens) {
          console.log("Error: Invalid input");
          return;
        }

        console.log("Tokens:", tokens);

        for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
          if (['sin', 'cos', 'tan'].includes(tokens[i]) && tokens[i + 1] === '(') {
            let argStart = i + 2;
            let argEnd = tokens.indexOf(')', argStart);
            if (argEnd === -1) {
              console.log("Error: Missing closing parenthesis");
              return;
            }

            let angle = parseFloat(tokens.slice(argStart, argEnd).join(''));
            let result;

            if (tokens[i] === 'sin') {
              result = Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
            } else if (tokens[i] === 'cos') {
              result = Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
            } else if (tokens[i] === 'tan') {
              result = Math.tan(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
            }

            tokens.splice(i, argEnd - i + 1, result.toString());
            i--;
          }
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
          if (['*', '/', '%'].includes(tokens[i])) {
            let left = parseFloat(tokens[i - 1]);
            let right = parseFloat(tokens[i + 1]);
            let result = tokens[i] === '*' ? left * right : tokens[i] === '/' ? left / right : left % right;
            tokens.splice(i - 1, 3, result.toString());
            i--;
          }
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
          if (['+', '-'].includes(tokens[i])) {
            let left = parseFloat(tokens[i - 1]);
            let right = parseFloat(tokens[i + 1]);
            let result = tokens[i] === '+' ? left + right : left - right;
            tokens.splice(i - 1, 3, result.toString());
            i--;
          }
        }

        userOutput.value = tokens[0];
      });
    });
  });

  document.getElementById("cut").addEventListener('click', () => {
    userInput.value = userInput.value.slice(0, -1);
  });

  clearbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    userInput.value = '';
    userOutput.value = '';
  });
}

calc();
<!-- header section -->
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="">Logo</a>
    <button>contribute here</button>
  </nav>
</header>

<!-- main -->
<main>
  <section>
    <!-- calculator wrapper div -->
    <div>
      <!-- input and output screens -->
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type to Calculate" id="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Output" readonly id="output">
        <button id="clear">Clear</button>
      </div>

      <!-- wrapper that contains number btns , operators -->
      <div>

        <!-- numbers -->
        <div>
          <input type="button" value="0" id="0" data-type="number">
          <input type="button" value="1" id="1" data-type="number">
          <input type="button" value="2" id="2" data-type="number">
          <input type="button" value="3" id="3" data-type="number">
          <input type="button" value="4" id="4" data-type="number">
          <input type="button" value="5" id="5" data-type="number">
          <input type="button" value="6" id="6" data-type="number">
          <input type="button" value="7" id="7" data-type="number">
          <input type="button" value="8" id="8" data-type="number">
          <input type="button" value="9" id="9" data-type="number">
        </div>

        <!-- operators btns -->

        <div>
          <input type="button" value="+" id="+" data-type="operator">
          <input type="button" value="-" id="-" data-type="operator">
          <input type="button" value="*" id="*" data-type="operator">
          <input type="button" value="/" id="/" data-type="operator">
          <input type="button" value="%" id="%" data-type="operator">
          <button id="calcBtn">Calculate</button>
          <button id="cut">X</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- scientific calculator -->

    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Sin" id="sin" data-type="Soperator">
      <input type="button" value="Cos" id="cos" data-type="Soperator">
      <input type="button" value="Tan" id="tan" data-type="Soperator">
      <input type="button" value="sin⁻¹" id="sin-in" data-type="Soperator">
      <input type="button" value="cos⁻¹" id="cos-in" data-type="Soperator">
      <input type="button" value="tan⁻¹" id="tan-in" data-type="Soperator">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
  </section>
</main>
<script src="cal.js"></script>




Please add the CSS and the steps to create the issue and the expected output in a [mcve]

JavaScript is case-sensetive. Cos is not cos.

As you might know, strings "Sin" and "sin" are not same. Your regexp /(\d+(\.\d+)?)|[+\-*/%()]|sin|cos|tan/g will only match 'sin', 'cos' and 'tan', and will not match strings like 'Sin', 'sIn', 'SIn' etc.
In order to match all combinations of lower and uppercase, use the 'i' flag for case-insensitive search: /(\d+(\.\d+)?)|[+\-*/%()]|sin|cos|tan/gi.
The last step would be to convert the string to lowercase so that it can be later used for comparison (tokens[i] === 'sin'). A simple way is to use the map method to convert all strings in tokens to lowercase:
tokens.map((token) => token.toLowerCase()). There may be more efficient ways to do this.
